# How to "subclass" a node.js module

Tags: node.js, inheritance, node-modules

I've been primarily a Perl coder for years, but also have a background in C++, so I'm coming from a "classical" OO background, and now learning node.js.  I just read through [The Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript](http://amzn.to/1EEOwpU), which did a good job of explaining the JS concept of OO to classically-minded people like me. But I'm left with a question, specifically related to node.js and inheritance.  Pardon me if I'm still using "classical" vocabulary to explain my problem.

Lets suppose I have a module `lib/foo.js`:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('Foo was called');
}

module.exports.foo = foo;
```

And I want to "subclass" this in another module `lib/bar.js`:

```
var foo = require('foo.js');

// Do some magic here with *.prototype, maybe?

function bar() {
    console.log('Bar was called');
}

module.exports.bar = bar;
```

Such that my main script can do this:

```
var bar = require('lib/bar.js');

bar.foo(); // Output "Foo was called"
bar.bar(); // Output "Bar was called"
```

Is this even possible? If so, what am I missing?

Or is this an anti-pattern? Or plain impossible? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did it, to override one method in the [request module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request).  **Warning**: many node modules are poorly designed for extension, including request, as they do way too much stuff in the constructor.  Not just a gazillion argument options, but starting up IO, connections, etc.  For example, request does the http connection (eventually) *as part of the constructor*.  There is no explicit `.call()` or `.goDoIt()` method.

In my example, I wanted to use querystring instead of qs to format forms.  My module is cleverly named "MyRequest".  In a separate file named myrequest.js you have:

```
var Request = require('request/request.js');
var querystring = require('querystring');

MyRequest.prototype = Object.create(Request.prototype);
MyRequest.prototype.constructor = MyRequest;

// jury rig the constructor to do "just enough".  Don't parse all the gazillion options
// In my case, all I wanted to patch was for a POST request 
    function MyRequest(options, callbackfn) {
        "use strict";
        if (callbackfn)
           options.callback = callbackfn;
        options.method = options.method || 'POST';          // used currently only for posts
        Request.prototype.constructor.call(this, options);  
           // ^^^  this will trigger everything, including the actual http request (icky)
           // so at this point you can't change anything more
    }

    // override form method to use querystring to do the stringify
    MyRequest.prototype.form = function (form) {
     "use strict";
        if (form) {
            this.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
            this.body = querystring.stringify(form).toString('utf8');
  // note that this.body and this.setHeader are fields/methods inherited from Request, not added in MyRequest.
            return this;
        }

        else
           return Request.prototype.form.apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

Then, in your application, instead of

```
var Request = require("request");
Request(url, function(err, resp, body)
  {
      // do something here
   });
```

you go

```
var MyRequest = require("lib/myrequest");
MyRequest(url, function(err, resp, body)
  {
      // do that same something here
   });
```

I'm not a JavaScript guru so there may be better ways...

Comment: Is this contained in a node.js module? AKA `lib/myrequest.js` or somesuch? Or does the code you pasted live in your main application?

Comment: I think this is along the right track, and provides some good clues, but it doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: I'm guessing that the 'request' module returns the object constructor, not an actual object, which is why your code works for you, but not for me.  I had to use `var foo = require('foo.js'); Bar.prototype = Object.create( foo.__proto__ )`, but was able to get roughly the same result as you, after some trial and error. Thank you!

Comment: @Flimzy correct.  Often I wish the JS/node docs would be a bit more clear about what is a Class, what is a Constructor / factory, and what is an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the specific solution I came up with to my sample code problem follows:

In `lib/foo.js`:

```
var Foo = function() {}

Foo.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('Foo was called!');
};

module.exports = new Foo;
```

In `lib/bar.js`:

```
var foo = require('./foo.js');

var Bar = function() {}

Bar.prototype = Object.create(foo.__proto__);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Foo;

Bar.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log('Bar was called!');
};

module.exports = new Bar;
```

Then in my test script:

```
var bar = require('lib/bar.js');

bar.foo(); // Output "Foo was called"
bar.bar(); // Output "Bar was called"
```